does it hurt to specify design around embodiments that have a low chance of being allowed in your patent application?
There are a few bad design arounds for my invention that have low chances of being allowed.
Is it possible that it would hurt any way to include these embodiments in the specifications?

“Design around” means to design a solution about as good as the claimed invention while avoiding the claims. That is not how you are using the term. Can you be clearer? Also it seems a very familiar question
